# Firebase 500 error when deploying after update JSON

Tags: vue.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have updated my firebase JSON to look like this (following FB documentation) in order to deploy to different hosting:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "brokers",
      "public": "dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "testing-brokers",
      "public": "dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Before it used to look like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting":
    {
      "target": "brokers",
      "public": "dist",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

The thing is that the code at the bottom works fine but when I use the one at the top (recommended by firebase documentation for multiple hosting) it give me a 500 error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.
```

This happens when I run `firebase deploy` alone

If I run `firebase deploy --only hosting:testing-brokers` it works fine
But if I run `firebase deploy --only hosting:brokers` I got the same error again (500).

Any idea?